# How to stop a thread left from a closed app when running the app again? C#

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, multithreading, .net-core

I have an .NET 5.0 WPF Application which consists of 2 threads: the **UI thread** and **another thread** that is supposed to always work in the background and get some live data from an API and save it to a MYSQL database. The UI thread then reads the database every time it gets updated and shows the data in a chart.

The problem is that **I need the data getting thread to run in the background, even after closing the UI**. When that happens, the thread normally saves the data to the database, but **once I start the app again a new data thread starts and then there are 2 threads doing the same thing** in the background.

I can't do an `Environment.Exit(0);` because then the database and the chart would have some 'holes' in it, it wouldn't be complete, unless I would keep the app's UI always running minimalized, but that's not efficient and not needed.

**I would want the app to somehow detect if a thread from its older instance is running and based on that either run a new thread or don't and get data saved by the still running thread from the database.**

For now, the thread is run on the MainWindow Load Event
It is is created this way:

```
        Thread StockMarketThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(updateData));

        public static void updateData()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                getsetData();        //gets data from API and updates the database
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are asking about interprocess communications (IPC). Do research, choose one.

Comment: If the background work always needs to run, it should run as a service, not as a thread in a UI process. If it does not always need to run, it should start and stop with the UI. An application that leaves zombie-threads is not a good design.

Comment: If it's got to be reading data constantly from an api, what happens when the user shuts their pc down? Sounds like this database should be on a server with a daemon or windows service reading data and saving it to the database. You could push notify changes from the server using signalr. Or connect them up using rabbitmq if this is all in the one premises.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. The application running in the background isn't that necessary, it just creates a chart with live data, so it's great to have, it can close when the computer would be shut down. I only have a question, if the other thread should work in the background, won't `Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;` work this way, if I would set the close button's event to `This.Close();` instead of `Application.Current.Shutdown();`? Would the thread work in the background then or would it still create its new instance each time the app would be started?

Comment: @TechrexStudios: Did you read my answer? A thread cannot outlive the process.

Comment: @mm8 Yes, I understand, but when it comes to that, is it better for this described purpose to create a service or something else? I cannot find an example of running a background thread as a foreground thread, the backend process part is a bit too general, could you only specify what may be the best option for that kind of work?

Comment: @TechrexStudios: Yes, if you want to get rid of the "holes". If you don't care about them, you could keep it as it is. Either way, a thread won't outlive the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A thread lives inside a process. When the process, which in this case is your WPF application, exits all threads in it stops.

You can run your worker thread as a *foreground* thread to prevent the WPF application from shutting down until the background work has finished but what you probably want to do is to move the background work to a separate (backend) process that runs regardless of whether your UI app is running.

That's the only way of "*getting [the] thread to run in the background, even after closing the UI [process]*" and avoid "holes" in the data.

The UI should just be a *consumer* of the data that is produced in another process that is typiclly running on a server of some kind.